# How to use Oracle Responsys with Java Application

Tags: java, email, responsys

In my Java Application I want to use **`Oracle Responsys`** to **trigger individual email in response to some activity detected by my web site**

**`Oracle Responsys`** is completely new for me and not able find out where to start.

I got **`SOAP API Developer’s Guide — Standard`** documentation, and trying to figure out myself. But seems to be I am not understanding the core concept of how to integrate **`Oracle Responsys`** in my application.

Please help on how to integrate **`Oracle Responsys`** into my web application? I am not able to find any Java SDK for **`Oracle Responsys`**, is there one available? If available from where I can get it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I am not understanding the core concept of how to integrate Oracle Responsys in my application.

The "core concept" is that your application sends requests to the Responsys server's API over HTTP / HTTPS.  Your application can (in theory) do this directly by crafting HTTP requests with the correct parameters / payloads / etc, and then parsing the results.  Alternatively, it can use either a generic framework (such as JAX-WS), or a specific client library to do most of the tedious stuff for you.

> I am not able to find any Java SDK for Oracle Responsys, is there one available.

Responsys provides both REST and SOAP based APIs, but at this time they don't appear to provide any (official) Java client-side libraries for either API.

I did find some 3rd-party client libraries on Github.  Rather than listing them, I suggest that you Google for `responsys api github` and start trawling the search results.

Questions that ask for recommendations on StackOverflow, are off topic, so I'm assuming that you are not asking for one.  But, you will need to do your own assessment of the completeness and fitness for purpose of the various library alternatives.

Comment: Thanks, I think `responsys api github` and `JAX-WS` will help me for this.